# How to find a match in 2 different 3d list

Tags: python, list, dataframe, multidimensional-array, jupyter-notebook

i have two list with the same length over 11 rows. I would like df[0] to find a match in any position in df2[0] and df[1] to find a match in any position df2[1] and etc.... Instead of me typing one by one is there a easier method?

```
df = [[[1, 5,7,9,12,13,17],
[2,17,18,23,32,34,45],
[3,5,11,33,34,36,45]],
[[6,21,22,50,56,58,72],
[7,5,12,13,55,56,74],
[8,23,24,32,56,58,64]]]

df2 =[[[100,5,12,15,27,32,54],
[120,10,17,18,19,43,55],
[99,21,32,33,34,36,54]],
[[41,16,32,45,66,67,76],
[56,10,11,43,54,55,56],
[77,12,16,18,19,21,23]]]
```

i would like my output to be like this.

```
output = [[[[5,12,],[17]],
  [[17,18],[32,34,36]]],
  [[[55,56],[32]],[[56]]]
```